# ElasticBeanstalk: Cant change environment type to load balanced in GUI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, load-balancing

Elastic Beanstalk. (Created with code star). Java. Spring Boot. EC2.

The documentation states that we can change the environment type within the GUI to load balanced from a single instance:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html

However, when trying it out. After the changes have taken hold and my environment was load balanced. Upon further deployments, my changes appear to have been reset and the environment type is now shown to be single-instance.

Upon examination of the service package, there is cloud formation that states the environment type

template.yml:

```
 EBConfigurationTemplate:
    Description: The AWS Elastic Beanstalk configuration template to be created for this project, which defines configuration settings used to deploy different versions of an application.
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref 'EBApplication'
      Description: The name of the sample configuration template.
      OptionSettings:
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
        OptionName: EnvironmentType
        Value: SingleInstance
```

Which must have overwritten any of the GUI changes that have been made by hand upon further deployment.

I presume such changes (anything already in cloud formation) must then be done through cloud formation and not be done by hand in the GUI? (What changes can be done by GUI is it changes related to .ebextensions files?)

Bonus: Has someone seen a GitHub project that have used ElasticBeanstalk with EC2 and hence must have done this in their cloud formation?

Answer (score 0):

> I presume such changes (anything already in cloud formation) must then be done through cloud formation and not be done by hand in the GUI?

Yes. It is a **bad practice** to manually modify resources created and managed by CFN, which can lead to issues. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html):

> changes made outside of CloudFormation can complicate stack update or deletion operations.

What happens when you do this, is so called [drift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html#what-is-drift). This means that CFN is simply not aware of any outside changes made to its resources. So once you start developing your solutions through CFN, every change to them should also be done through CFN.

Sadly I'm not sure what you are after in the bonus questions, thus can't comment on it.